# Как отправить видео через телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Как отправить видеоролик через телеграм бота?
вот пример кода, но он не работает

```
 elif message.text.lower() == 'example':
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
        keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        keyboard.row('example')
        bot.send_video(message.chat.id, 'http://example.com/video.mp4')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала его нужно открыть

```
video = open('video.mp4', 'rb')
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video)
```

Подробнее можете прочитать здесь https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI